# Fur shading using GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I develop a 3D Engine using GLSL and I want to add the fur shading effect.

[image]

I did some researches to find a tutorial that explains correctly the 'Fur shading' technique and the best site I've found is the following one :

http://www.xbdev.net/directx3dx/specialX/Fur/

However it uses the DirectX API and HSLS. But in short it's very close to OpenGL and GLSL.
I understood that I have to render the scene in several pass with the same couple of shaders. To give the impression of spikes I just have decrease the alpha value for each layer. So the last one is almost transparent.

[image]

For example if I want to render a fur with 5 layers on plane I must render my scene 5 times. With DirectX it seems to be easier that OpenGL because HLSL has a keyword 'pass' integrated to render the scene with a multi pass. But I think I have to use Frame Buffer Object (FBO) with the OpenGL API using render buffers or textures. I think I must render the scene several times and for each time I register the color buffer in a different texture each time (attached all on a FBO or several FBO by texture). At the end the process I will have a unique color buffer which is the result of the superposition of the privious textures. Is my idea is correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a multi pass equivalent in opengl, maybe someone with more experience can come in and correct me, but the way I'd do it is I'd make the FurLength a uniform and call glDrawElements multiple times after setting the uniform value for FurLength.

Comment: Ok. So the principle is first to bind my shaders. Next if I have five layers, my scene will be rendered 5 times with the sames vertex and fragment shaders (so 5 calls to glDrawElement like you said). So for each pass the pixel shader will update the frame buffer. So FBOs are useless. Is it correct ?

Comment: Thanks to your answer I complety understood the process. Actually, it's like rendering several planes but with a unique one at the beginning of the process. Thanks again for your answer! Bye.

Comment: this looks like an excellent example for Geometry shader. you pass the base primitive to it and it will generate the N-layers itself by duplicating/scaling/offsetting the original primitive. alpha can be changed in Vertex (controlled by the primitive/vertex index) ... so you can do this in single pass from your code point of view